# Azure Web App Blazor Server - Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: There was an error with the transport

Tags: azure, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to set a new environnement for a website in a Linux Azure Web App with B1 plan.

My production website is working perfectly with a B2 plant ( also in Linux ).
But with this new environnement, I get this error :

> [2021-08-19T09:01:46.572Z] Error: Failed to start the transport
> 'WebSockets': Error: There was an error with the transport.

Of course, all settings for web sockets are set :

[image: Azure Web App Settings]

I have a custom subdomain for this webapp with a valid SSL

[image: DNS]

As I say all is working in production with the same code base version.
I have the exactly same issue with the admin panel... I don't know why this come with this new website that share the same pipeline, release etc...

Comment: Have you checked this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66805734/signalr-in-azure-app-service-not-working-for-websockets

Some infos in the comments.

Comment: @NicolaBiada yep, I already checked a lot of SO questions ^^'

Comment: Have you tried to export your B1 & B2 configuration from Azure and do a compare?

Comment: Have you an authorized Signalr endpoint? Try to convert to anonymous just for test.

Comment: @NicolaBiada I have workerSize & CurrentWorkerSize set to 0 in the B1 plan ( B2 plan have 1 ). And SignalR is fully manage by blazor, so not directly, but I get the error in anonymous pages

Comment: Moving to the B2 plan makes app working....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236193/discussion-between-orcusz-and-nicola-biada).

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this issue on Github:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20636

The problem could be in the `skipNegotiation` parameter, you have to set it to **false** instead of **true**:

```
    var object = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(GAME_HUB_URL, {
        skipNegotiation: false,
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
        accessTokenFactory: () => state.userReducer.user.token,
      })
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
      .build();
```

Comment: I'm not using directly signalR